# Mocha synchronous "before all" hook timeout

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a Mocha test suite that intermittently fails with the following message:

```
  1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

The slimmed down code looks like this:

```
const rewiremock      = require("rewiremock").default;
const sinon           = require("sinon");

// Some more imports

let readFileSync;
let serverConfiguration;
let testingModule;

before(
  function ()
  {
    // Some mocking of the form:

    rewiremock(
      "fs"
    ).by(
      (
        mock
      ) =>
      {
        const realFs  = mock.requireActual("fs");
        readFileSync = sinon.spy(realFs, "readFileSync");

        return realFs;
      }
    );

    const originalModule = require("./path/to/my/mod");

    const fakeModule = {
      myMethod() {
        // Some behaviour-altering code and then:
        originalModule.myMethod();
      }
    };

    testingModule = rewiremock.proxy(
      "./path/to/testing/module",
      {
        "./path/to/my/mod"  : fakeHttpUiServerFactory
      }
    );

    console.log("one");

    // Some more mocking

    console.log("two");

    // Aaaand more mocking

    console.log("three");

    // Initialization of a configuration object

    serverConfiguration = {
        "nothing" : "special here"
    };

    console.log("four");
  }
);
```

The hook is synchronous; it does not have a `done` parameter (as shown), nor does the code return anything. I added some logs to try to see where the function stops before it times out, but every log is printed. It seems to execute the function just fine, but then it stops long enough for the timeout to occur.

Is there anything else I can try to add to help debug this issue when it happens? Again, this happens intermittently, so it is hard to give proper reproduction steps besides "I run this code". If the full version of the code would help, I can provide it (kind of, it is proprietary so you will see a lot of `myThis` and `myThat`, but the structure itself would remain the same).

Comment: This started to happen for once I updated sinon. I think the fake timer implementation is buggy

Answer (score -1):

Inside your before function, you can set **this.timeout = xxxx** and increase the time. I usually set it to 10000. There might be a better solution, but this is how I fix this issue for me.